# Screenshot image from a movie with a blue alien and spaceship

Tags: story-identification, movie

I found this image from a meme site. The blue bald guy seems to be an alien. There's also some kind of spaceship in the background. So, I think it's a sci-fi movie.

I blocked some parts of the image because it contains some "dark" text. So, I suggest that you do not Google search this image if you think you'll get offended.

PS: I did a Google image search and still do not know the title of this movie (if it is a movie).

[image: Image to identify]

Comment: That's Watchmen.  Dr. Manhattan in the foreground, Night Owl in the background.

Comment: And the unmasked Rorschach (Walter Kovacs) in the midground.

Comment: @AdamLimbert We don't add work tags to story id questions once the work is known. It looks odd i.e. why ask a question if you know the work to tag it? and isn't really needed the question is about identification not the work.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot no problem, will take note of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is *[Watchmen](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0409459/)* (2009).  The blue guy is Doctor Manhattan.

[image]

The scene depicted is at the end of the film, in which Doctor Manhattan is having his final verbal confrontation with Rorschach in Antarctica.  Also visible in the background, by the entrance to Ozymandias's base, is Nite Owl.

**Warning: Spoilers + NSFW (gore)**

Comment: Seems it's the one. Thank you @Buzz